# Using JdbcMetadataStore Along with s3-inbound-streaming-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

We are reading files from S3 bucket using Streaming Inbound Channel Adapter referring at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws

In order to avoiding duplicate file reading across instances I am planning to use
JdbcMetadataStore. So the question is can we use S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with JdbcMetadataStore ? (we don't have/want to use AWS MetadataStore)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes" you can use `JdbcMetadataStore` based on a shared RDBMS for the mentioned `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to avoid file reading duplication on several instance of your application.